# Strange use of conditional たら

Tags: meaning, conditionals

I'm having trouble making sense of the sentence below. (It's taken from 『いつかこの恋を思い出してきっと泣いてしまう』.) I would appreciate anyone's help.

> 休み取れたんだったら、有給取ったのに
>   私これからぎゅうぎゅうの地下鉄乗るっちゃん

Answer (score 2):

The subjects are left out...

「(あなたが)休み(を)取れたんだったら、(私も)有給(休暇を)取ったのに。」

"If you could have taken a day off (today), I would have taken a paid holiday, too... (so that we could stay together one more day...)"

有給 is short for 有給休暇 "paid leave from work".

Comment: これコンテクスト知らないと無理やんな・・

Answer (score 0):

The author is complaining that even though he was able to take a paid leave, he is going to spend it in a crowded, packed subway train.

The rest of the conditional is left implicit:
休み取れたんだったら
If you are able to take a vacation (you should spend it in a nice place)